# Ionic 2 how to bind JSON to html page components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have this JSON

```
{   

  "_index": "search_posts",   "_type": "posts",   "_id": "12345", 
  "_score": 0,   
  "_source": {
      "alias_id": 0,
      "user_id": 1,
      "name": "demo",
      "email": "demo@account.com",
      } 
}
```

I get the JSON this way in my page.ts :

```
this.userDetails = this.navParams.get('params');
```

when I try to do something like this in the page.html to get the data it throws an error

`<p id=userName>{{userDetails._source.name}}</p>`

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_source' of undefined

Comment: the error is caused when I try to access  userDetails._source where the _source refers to my json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access the properties from that object, before it's being initialized (maybe the view is trying to show it, but the component code has not yet initialize it). Try by doing it but this time, using the *elvis operator*

```
<p id="userName">{{ userDetails?._source.name }}</p>
```

That way, if `userDetails` is null (or undefined), angular won't try to access to its properties.